# Making every variable in this code Dynamic Visual Basic 2010

Tags: arrays, vb.net, checkbox

Sorry for the long piece of code. In a game I'm designing, I have this code starting at the checkbox.checked if statement currently repeated 5 times for each checkbox clicked--each checkbox is equal to a card within the players hand in the game.

What I'd like to know is what can I do to make it mostly dynamic. Namely the CardCheckBox1.Checked  Object/Method. As stated above the code is repeated 5 times, as I have 5 existing checkboxes. Is there a way to place the checkboxes into an array or collection so when I click a check box and hit the play button it will be the equivalent of hitting CardCheckBox2.checked = true, CardCheckBox2.checked = true, etc. Once I figure how to make that part dynamic I can finally start making the rest of the code dynamic, because I assume procedure for making a dynamic label code would be very similar to the checkboxes, etc.

I've had

```
Dim CardCheckBoxArray() As CheckBox = {CardCheckBox1, CardCheckBox2, CardCheckBox3, CardCheckBox4, CardCheckBox5}
```

posted at the Modular Level, in the Form_Load Procedure, and even the Play_Button Procedure, but I always end up with a nullreference exception on the CardCheckBox(n).Checked Portion of the code when I do

```
If CardCheckBoxArray(0).Checked = True And Player1HandGroup(Number1).QuantityInteger > 0 Then
```

So I don't know where to go with it. The long piece of code is my entire PlayButton_Click procedure, except for the other CardCheckBox if statements.

```
Private Sub PlayButton_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles PlayButton.Click
        Dim n As Integer
        Dim WeaponDiscardInteger As Integer = 1
        AtkPlayerDialog.ShowDialog()
        'Code for choosing which player to attack
        If AtkPlayerDialog.DialogResult = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Cancel Then
            n = 2
        ElseIf AtkPlayerDialog.DialogResult = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
            n = 1
        ElseIf AtkPlayerDialog.DialogResult = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Abort Then
            n = 3
        ElseIf AtkPlayerDialog.DialogResult = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Retry Then
            n = 4
        ElseIf AtkPlayerDialog.DialogResult = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Ignore Then
            n = 5
        End If

'playing card 1
        If CardCheckBox1.Checked = True And Player1HandGroup(Number1).QuantityInteger > 0 Then
            'Subtract Hitpoints when damage is delt
            Player1HandGroup(n).HitPoints -= Player1HandGroup(Number1).DamageInteger
            HitPoints1.Text = Player1HandGroup(1).HitPoints.ToString
            HitPoints2.Text = Player1HandGroup(2).HitPoints.ToString
            HitPoints3.Text = Player1HandGroup(3).HitPoints.ToString
            HitPoints4.Text = Player1HandGroup(4).HitPoints.ToString
            HitPoints5.Text = Player1HandGroup(5).HitPoints.ToString
            'When player plays hand, card quantity is removed from hand to discard pile.
            Player1HandGroup(Number1).QuantityInteger -= 1
            DiscardGroup(Number1).QuantityInteger += 1
            'Shuffle Deck from Discard Pile if Deck is out of cards
            Call DiscardPile()
            'Reset Number Generator, unless weapon isn't discard
            Number = (DeckGroup(Rnd.Next(0, DeckGroup.Count)).ID)
            If DeckGroup(Number).QuantityInteger > 0 Then
                'Grab New Card From Deck
                DeckGroup(Number).QuantityInteger -= 1
                Player1HandGroup(Number).QuantityInteger += 1
                Card1Type = Player1HandGroup(Number).CardType
                CardCheckBox1.Text = Player1HandGroup(Number).CardNameString
                Number1 = Number
            Else
                Call PlayElse()
            End If
```

Comment: Couple of suggestions if I may, to make your code easier to manage... Use a `Select Case` on the `AtkPlayerDialog` checks; Loop through the `PlayerHandGroup` instead of hardcoding the indices. Try to use `AndAlso` instead of `And` in your conditional statements (and also `OrElse` instead of `Else`).

Comment: I do not see how a Select Case would shorten up my AtkPlayer Dialog code. That part works fine as it is anyway. Both the check box and play1handgroup have to be true--if I short circuit it, the two then the results will be wrong...

Comment: Nor worries, they were only suggestions, so feel free to disregard. `Select Case` would avoid having to write `AtkPlayerDialog.DialogResult` five times and less repetition makes for more maintainable code. `AndAlso` does not short-cuircuit, it ensures that both statements are true, but it is much better than `And`, because it avoids executing the second statement if the first one is false (very useful it you have `If something IsNot Nothing AndAlso Something = "Whatever" then ...` if you have `And` in thi case you will get an exception if `something` is nothing.

Answer (score 0):

I f you use the checkbox array inside/through most your form code then move it out o the form load event right the way up to the form level scope. when it is inside the forn_load event subroutine, that is not the same as module level scope.

so you would have......

```
Dim CardCheckBoxArray() As CheckBox = {CardCheckBox1, CardCheckBox2, CardCheckBox3, CardCheckBox4, CardCheckBox5}


Sub Form_Load(blah blah blah)
  ...
End Sub

Sub Play_Button(blah blah blah)
  ...
End Sub
```

etc etc

Comment: I just posted it in the play_button procedure. It is finally working! But I realize now that I may need to rethink some of my code. Thank you very much though.

Comment: I figured it out myself and made the code completely dynamic after Zaf's wise words.